# Name spacing your modules in Python

Tags: python

I have several repos that I want to name space. All of the repos follow the standard Python folder structures where

```
repo1 - repo1 - __init__.py
```

Outermost `repo1` folder is the root folder and the inner `repo1` folder is the root of the module. All of these repos will be installed using

```
pip install -e .
```

Currently, import statements like the following is used to import these modules.

```
import repo1
import repo2
import repo3
```

Is there a way to name space these modules so that I can have

```
import mymodule.repo1
import mymodule.repo2
import mymodule.repo3
```

I have to achieve the name spacing while keeping the repos separate. Merging the repos is not an option at this moment.

Comment: https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/

Comment: Why can't/don't you want to merge the repos? Is it because of file name conflicts? If not, then the answer would be to add an extra directory in each repo and install as before. Eg. The new directory structure is `repo1/mymodule/repo1/__init__.py`. No need for an init in the new directory(s). See https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/

Comment: We can't merge the repos because we are a financial institution and only some employees have access to certain source code. Separating the repos was already done to solve that issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementation details depends on your needs for version support and distribution, but take a look at setuptools [`namespace_packages`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#namespace-packages), this will do the work.

As pointed above, packaging site has an [useful page](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/#creating-a-namespace-package) on namespaced packaging.

---

Example for native namespaces (python >=3.3). Project layout for isolated repos:

```
project_root1
├── finance_namespace  # no __init__ file here, this is important
│   └── repo1
│       ├── __init__.py  
│       └── module1.py
└── setup.py

===============================

# setup.py
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name='repo1',
    version='1',
    description='',
    long_description='',
    author='Big bank',
    author_email='john@bank.com',
    license='MIT',
    packages=['finance_namespace.repo1'],
    zip_safe=False,
)
```

Now, by making `cd project_root1 && pip install -e .` you should be able to do

```
>>> from finance_namespace.repo1 import module1
>>> module1.func()
```

Comment: I followed your steps to set up each repo in this way. And then I did "pip install -e ." inside each repo. Only the first repo is installed correctly. "import mymodule.repo1" works but "import mymodule.repo2" cannot be found.

Comment: What's your requirements for python version?

Comment: Python version 3.5.2

Comment: I've added example